# How can I use BitTorrent DHT to get a P2P connection between two nodes?

Tags: node.js, bittorrent, handshake, dht

I know that BitTorrent DHT can be used to coordinate torrents without the need for a tracker. Now, I would like to build a P2P network of nodes and I would prefer to avoid the hassle of developing my own discovery / signaling / handshaking / NAT traversal.

So I was wondering: is there any library (preferably nodejs) that I can use to just:

- Generate an identifier on a node A.
- On a node B, use A's identifier to connect to A.
- Both nodes get some callback with a socket, ready to write on?

I mean, this should be somehow part of the handshaking protocol for BitTorrent, but instead of directly using the torrent protocol to send data, I would like to directly get to talk with the other node and implement my own protocol.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The bittorrent DHT and the bittorrent data transfer protocol are separate things. So yes, it is possible to find other IP/Port contacts through the DHT and connect to them with a custom protocol.